# XSL printing linebreak but leave out last line break

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document with let's say 300 records.. I am running through each record and if certain criteria are met I am writing data to a text file with a linefeed after each record. I have this working a s expected except for the fact that after the last record is printed a space is being added and this results in an error in the system receiving the file. I can not use position as the last record in my xml does not always meet the criteria. Any thoughts how to include a linefeed for each record matched except the last match?

```
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>  
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>  
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>  
    </Group>
</Worker>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="Worker_Sync"/>    
<xsl:template match="Worker_Sync">

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Worker">


    <xsl:for-each select="Group[Field[@name = 'LastName'] = 'Smith']">
        <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Field[@name = 'LastName'])"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>, last
        <xsl:value-of select="last()"/><br/>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

NEW XML

```
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">True</Field> 
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
```

Expected Result
Smith (linefeed)
Smith (linefeed)
Jones - Fulltime (no linefeed)

So I want to select anyone with the last name Smith and write their last name only and anyone with the Fulltime = true and write their last name and the word Fulltime... I thought I'd be able to solve the 2nd piece once I had the first piece but that was not the case..

Comment: XSL doesn't output anything you don't tell it to output. You haven't given us anywhere near enough information to give you specific advice, but the answer is to rewrite your stylesheet logic so it Doesn't Do That. Or fix the other application so it has the intelligence needed to ignore that linebreak. If you want us to say anything more, you'll have to give us something concrete to work with; mindreading is not available as a free service.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please extend your question with your input XML, your XSLT code, the XML output you expect and the one you actually get.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info.. I understand that xsl is not outputting anything I don;t tell it to. Inside my if statement I am writing the necessary data as well as a line feed for each record that matches the criteria. My issue is that when the last record is matched a linefeed is written and remains in the file. I was just looking for some advice on how to rewrite the stylesheet to include a linefeed after all records but the last one that matches. Changing the downstream system is not an option.. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide..

Comment: "I can not use position as the last record in my xml does not always meet the criteria" - that depends entirely on the stylesheet structure - if you simply apply templates to all nodes and then use `if` checks inside the template to decide whether a node "meets the criteria" then yes, but if instead you use predicates to select only the nodes that "meet the criteria" and only `apply-templates` (or `for-each`) over those nodes then you _can_ use `position()`.

Comment: We absolutely need to see XML and XSLT code to be able to give reasonable advice (I am repeating myself).

Comment: When you say "I can not use position" do you mean "I can not use `position()`"?

Comment: We can't read your mind. There are too many possible ways to have written a stylesheet that resembles what you have described. That makes it impossible to suggest a fix. If you can post a simplified version of your stylesheet, and sample intput, which demonstrates the problem we may be able to help you. Otherwise, this is essentially "my program doesn't do what I want", to which the only possible answer is "that's too bad, I hope you get it fixed."

Comment: One possible suggestion: It may be easier to change the problem definition to output a newline _before_ each record rather than after each record. Then you just have to suppress the first rather than the last, which may be an easier test to implement.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback - I was pulled off of this for a production issue and I am now back to it. Please find some sample code below.. What I would like is to be able to select the two employees with last name Smith and have them in a result set where I could identify the last item using position().. In the current code both positions return 1. Thanks in advance for any help you experts can provide this xslt newbie..

Comment: added code to original post as advised - Placing the space at the beginning of the file would also break the file. If I can get the position tracking working I think I can manage to write the if statement to leave out the linefeed for the last returned record.. Thanks in advance for your feedback..

Comment: Could you also add the *exact* output you expect to get from the given input?

Comment: Michael your answer was EXACTLY what I was hoping for.. Thanks for your feedback it is much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running through each record and if certain criteria are met I am
>   writing data to a text file with a linefeed after each record.
>   ...
>   What I would like is to be able to select the two employees with last
>   name Smith and have them in a result set where I could identify the
>   last item using position().

I am going to hold onto these statements, because there are a lot of other things here that make no sense. Now, assuming your *real* input looks like this:

```
<Worker_Sync>
    <Worker>
        <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>  
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>  
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>  
        </Group>
    </Worker>
</Worker_Sync>
```

you can use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Worker_Sync/Worker/Group[Field[@name='LastName']='Smith']">
        <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Field[@name='LastName'])"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce the following *text* output:

```
SMITH
SMITH
```

Note that there is no line feed after the last SMITH.

---

**EDIT:**
If I understand correctly your amended requirement, try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Worker_Sync/Worker/Group[Field[@name='LastName']='Smith' 
                                                   or 
                                                   Field[@name='Fulltime']='True']">
        <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Field[@name='LastName'])"/>
        <xsl:if test="Field[@name='Fulltime']='True'">
            <xsl:text> - Fulltime</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Now I am going to muddy the waters I think and not sure what I am asking can be done. Let's say I had 2 additional worker records with the last name Flynn and an additional Field named Fulltime

Comment: New XML code and expected results posted to original post.. Thought I'd be able to work out the 2nd piece but not having any luck... Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: @user3266089 I have added a modified version to my answer above. P.S. Why is your XML input still incorrect (no root element, spurious dashes), even after you have modified it?

Comment: Thanks for your help - What if I had to have my results look more like this

Comment: So one of the Smith records was changed to fulltime true and for each Smith found I had to output Last name in Caps as it is and for each Fulltime I had to output last name in lower - Fulltime - OriginalHireDt so I would need to lines for the name that matched Smith and was Fulltime.. I can not seem to get the logic right - I can produce the two records but they end up on one line because both if statements match and the space is not applied until after the last if statement is closed..

Comment: Added new xslt code above you can see how i added the if but can not figure out the logic to produce expected result

Comment: @user3266089 I suggest you post a new question with this (new) problem. The one here is already confusing enough.